# React admin select input default empty value

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, react-admin

I am using react admin's select input& I am currently on version 3.13 and this version allows the attribute 'allowEmpty' to show an extra empty field in the selection dropdown. Also we can use 'initialValue' prop to set the initial value for the inputs. But is there a way to set the empty value as default value selected for my dropdown?
In my case one of the values from the possible choices is getting defaulted

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on your problem? When you have set the allowEmpty prop, the SelectInput should be empty by default. I was able to reproduce the desired behavior with the follwing code:

```
<SelectInput
  source="test"
  label="Test"
  allowEmpty
  choices={[
    { id: "1", name: "yo" },
    { id: "2", name: "yoyo" }
  ]}
  initialValue="" // This line can be omitted
/>
```

One problem I could think of would be when you have set default values for the `<Form />` component you're using, `<SimpleForm />` per default.

Comment: Hi, that's not an answer but a follow-up question. Discussions that are not questions take part in the comments section, not under answers.